# How to do the image fade-in effect upon scroll (like mashable.com)

Tags: javascript, animation, fade, effect

I'm wondering about the fade-in effect for images on mashable.com (see http://mashable.com/2009/08/14/google-android-logo-remixes/ for example)

As you scroll to the image, it fades in. It's not fading in on page load, only upon the actual appearance of the item on-screen.

Thanks.

Comment: You can determine whether an HTML element is visible on a page using JQuery, and call any function as soon as it becomes visible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's achieved with the jQuery plugin [Lazy Load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload).

EDIT: Here's the code they used:

```
if(! navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match('ipad')){
  $('#primary img').lazyload({effect:'fadeIn',placeholder:'/wp-content/themes/v6/_base/img/blank.png'});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was something like "delay load" and "lazy load" it is :)

Answer (score 1):

Found the mootools version of the lazyload http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-lazyload

Answer (score 1):

There is a [jQuery version of lazyload](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/lazy-load) too.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly, the Lazy Load plugin not works in most actual browsers, [according the own author says in the official web site](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload).

But the [jQuery Appear Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/appear) do almost the same thing!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A [YUI version](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/imageloader/) is available too.  In fact, Lazy Load was inspired by it.