# Load images when the user scrolls down the page -

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been noticing a trend in blogs where the images don't load until you scroll down the page and the images appear in the view screen.

I imagine that this must be some sort of jquery magic, but after some googling I haven't been able to figure out how it works. Does anyone know how this is done?

EDIT: If you want to see an example of this behavior, check out the portfolios on behance.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's achieved with the jQuery plugin [Lazy Load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload).

also look at this question from the [jquery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/fade-up-images-once-scrolled-into-viewable-area)

Look at a similar question 
**Source**: [How to do the image fade-in effect upon scroll (like mashable.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750776/how-to-do-the-image-fade-in-effect-upon-scroll-like-mashable-com)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Customize the effects as per your needs.

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload